# Extend nodejs request object

Tags: node.js

How can I extend node.js request object and add custom methods and properties to it? I need to be able to access `this` from node's request though since I'll need the url and such.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The request object passed to the `http.createServer` callback is an `http.IncomingMessage` object. To augment the request object, you can add methods to `http.IncomingMessage.prototype`.

```
var http = require('http');

http.IncomingMessage.prototype.userAgent = function () {
  return this.headers['user-agent'];
}
```

To add an accessor property:

```
Object.defineProperty(http.IncomingMessage.prototype, 'userAgent', {
  get: function () {
    return this.headers['user-agent'];
  }
}
```

If your existing object has its methods defined in the constructor body, you can use delegation:

```
function AugmentedRequest() { 
  this.userAgent = function () {}
}

AugmentedRequest.call(request); //request now has a userAgent method
```

Another method, that doesn't involve augmenting the `request` object is to use composition.

```
var extendedRequest = {
  get userAgent() {
    this.request.headers['user-agent'];
  }
}

createServerCallback(function (req, res) {
  var request = Object.create(extendedRequest);
  request.request = req;
});
```

This technique is heavily employed in [koa](https://github.com/koajs/koa) to wrap Node objects.

Comment: Ok that's nice. If a have a custom build object with properties and methods is it then possible to merge that into IncomingMessage?

Comment: That is awesome. Which method is preferred?

Comment: One way would be to iterate over all of your methods and add them to the `request` object. `for(var key in object) { req[key] = object[key]; }`. `this` will then refer to the `request` object.

Comment: @c.P.u1 when i run npm install http, it downloads folder with only package.json in it, and no js files, what is the reason???

Answer (score 3):

You can pass your own classes into the [createServer](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_createserver_options_requestlistener) function.

```js
const {createServer, IncomingMessage, ServerResponse} = require('http')

// extend the default classes
class CustomReponse extends ServerResponse {
  json(data) {
    this.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    this.end(JSON.stringify(data))
  }
  status(code) {
    this.statusCode = code
    return this
  }
}

class CustomRequest extends IncomingMessage {
   // extend me too
}

// and use as server options
const serverOptions = {
  IncomingMessage: CustomRequest,
  ServerResponse: CustomReponse,
}

createServer(serverOptions, (req, res) => {
  // example usage
  res.status(404).json({ 
    error: 'not found', 
    message: 'the requested resource does not exists' 
  })
}).listen(3000)
```