# Why in DefinitelyTyped `http.IncomingMessage` defined as interface, not a class?

Tags: node.js, typescript

As said documentation of Node.js, `http.IncomingMessage` [is a class](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_incomingmessage), not an interface. So why in DefinitelyTyped `http.IncomingMessage` [defined as interface](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/e2988a134ec9fa51deb43487231ac607265ba088/node/index.d.ts#L694)?

Now in my code I can not do this:

```ts
import * as http from 'http';
let Request = http.IncomingMessage;
```

TypeScript error:

> [ts] Property 'IncomingMessage' does not exist on type 'typeof "http"'.

I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Its class then you should use it like : `let Request = http.IncomingMessage();`

Comment: @ranakrunal9, no, `http.IncomingMessage` for TypeScript defined as interface, so interface can't call constructor.

Comment: So for defining variable of type `http.IncomingMessage` you should do  : `let Request: http.IncomingMessage;`

Comment: @ranakrunal9, just open an editor and check yourself. It's not works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that really not exists Node.js API for extends `http.IncomingMessage`. This way more as hack and not normal extends:

```
http.IncomingMessage.prototype.absoluteUri = function absoluteUri(path) {
  // ...
};
```

I [found this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26337542/1716560) answer to extends `http.IncomingMessage`:

```
var extendedRequest = {
  get userAgent() {
    this.request.headers['user-agent'];
  }
}

createServerCallback(function (req, res) {
  var request = Object.create(extendedRequest);
  request.request = req;
});
```