# Build failing after typescript update

Tags: angular, typescript, build

I am getting the following error on npm run prod:build

```
node_modules/@types/connect/index.d.ts(21,42): error TS2689: 
Cannot extend an interface 'http.IncomingMessage'. 
Did you mean 'implements'?
```

But my `package.json` file does not have a `@types/connect.`

I am using **typescript** version 3.4.5

```
@types/node '~6.0.60'
```

Should I upgrade `@types/node`?

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41390781/why-in-definitelytyped-http-incomingmessage-defined-as-interface-not-a-class

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why in DefinitelyTyped \`http.IncomingMessage\` defined as interface, not a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41390781/why-in-definitelytyped-http-incomingmessage-defined-as-interface-not-a-class)